# How to subset a dataframe by unique character in R?

Tags: r, subset

I would like to create a new dataframe from existing one. My df looks like this:

```
X                Y
12            ABC_SS
23            B49
45            G56_SS
```

I would like to subset new dataset that will have only Y values that includes "_SS" in Y. How can i do that, please?

This doesnt work:

```
newdf <-subset(df,df$Y %in% "_SS")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grepl` in `base R` to match substring

```
subset(df, grepl("_SS", Y))
```

---

Or another option is `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     filter(str_detect(Y, "_SS$"))
```